# CSS in body of SSRS subscription email

Tags: html, css, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

As per the title is this possible?

It seems to only pick up the HTML and ignore the CSS which is just displayed as text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The content of the comment block of a subscription is embedded as a table in the email output, so you won't be able to include CSS in a `<style>` tag as expected.

An option is to use an inline style attribute, which is applied to the email content. For example:

```
<span style="font: 14px Lucida, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Test email</span>
```

[This page](http://inlinestyler.torchboxapps.com/styler/convert/) can help with conversion from a CSS block to inline styles so you don't have to do it by hand.